# 5 years Older=I am 5 years her senior

Tags: synonyms

Good day,

My question is, let's say you have a girlfriend at the moment, and a random question has popped from one of your friends who is tagging along with the two of you.

> Your friend: what is your age gap? Obviously, you guys are not at the
>   same age.
>
> You: well, I am **2 years her senior**(rather than **2 years older
>   answer**)

Have I answered it correctly? Also, I think *2 years her senior* is more impressive to ear than *older*, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. You're also correct that "two years her senior" potentially makes the age difference sound a bit more impressive. The question, then, would be whether you want to sound like your age difference is impressive. Are you trying to imply that you are much older and wiser than your girlfriend?

Anyway, it doesn't forcibly mean that, but it's a possible connotation. It's also rather formal sounding, which might not be what you want in this context. If a native speaker said this to me when I asked about his age difference with his girlfriend, I'd suspect he might be stuffy, pompous, or both.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Regarding 'stuffy/pompous', I am no native english speaker, and let's set the situation in a casual talk. My goal here is not to sound arrogant but rather impressive in terms of word usage. In addition, if you set your tone right as you speak, would it still be sound stuffy/arrogant in a casual talk?(I need to ff-up this coz it is more likely that I'm gonna use this in the future, thx)

Comment: I can't think of a way to use this in casual talk without sounding a bit weird. It's a great construction in the right situations, though. To practice with it for now, I can only recommend avoiding it entirely in the first person and using it in slightly more formal situations when comparing the ages of other people.